# Compare data in 2 excel workbooks (unsorted data)

Tags: vba, excel

i am comparing the data in 2 workbooks, the column headers are in the same order, they are: ID, DepartmentName, Name, SalesAmount, StartDate, End Date.

Currently i am comparing all the cells in sheet 1 to sheet 2 (for example: cell A1 in sheet 1 to cell A1 in sheet 2 ). However, now the data in sheet 2 is in a different order so my current method of comparing will not work.

If sheet 1 contains the correct data, i want to be able to match the correct rows to sheet 2 and check the data still matches. For the rows that are not present in sheet 2 display a table to notify me of which IDs are missing.

Code which compares cell to cell and identifies differences:

```
For Each mycell In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtSheet2).UsedRange
    If Not mycell.Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtSheet1).Cells(mycell.Row, mycell.Column).Value Then        
        mycell.Interior.Color = vbRed
        difference = difference + 1
    End If
Next
```

Any advice or help will be greatly appreciated! thank you

Comment: You need to show what you have done so far.

Comment: @ChipsLetten I have added my code so far

Comment: cant you sort the two sheets with the same criteria before doing the matching?

Comment: So, is the ID column the main identifier? I think this is what you want but please confirm. If an ID on sheet 1 doesn't exist on sheet 2 then write the details from sheet 1 to sheet 3. Should the code also check that when an ID exists on both sheets that the values on sheet 2 match those on sheet 1?

Comment: The ID column is the main identifier, yes so if the row with does not exist in sheet 2 then i need to create a table of the missing IDs. If the ID exists in both sheets then the code needs to check the data in the columns is the same in both sheets and increment a match counter (which I am currently doing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read down the list of "good" IDs and for each one use the `Range.Find` method to look for the entry in shtSheet2. If not found, copy the "good" trade data to the output sheet. If found, then loop through the data items comparing them. Here's the code:

```
Dim sourceId As Range
Dim testIdData As Range
Dim outputRange As Range
Dim cellFound As Range
Dim columnNum As Integer
Dim copyTheData As Boolean
Dim difference As Integer

Const NUM_COLUMNS_DATA As Integer = 6 '

    ' Assumes that worksheet variables are already defined
    Set sourceId = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtSheet1).Range("A1")
    Set testIdData = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtSheet2).Range("A1")
    Set outputRange = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtSheet3).Range("A1")

    ' Extend testIdData to cover all rows of data
    Set testIdData = testIdData.Resize(testIdData.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count)

    Do Until sourceId.Value = ""
        copyTheData = False
        ' Look for ID in test data
        Set cellFound = testIdData.Find(What:=sourceId.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
        If cellFound Is Nothing Then
            ' This entry not found, so copy to output
            copyTheData = True
            outputRange.Resize(ColumnSize:=NUM_COLUMNS_DATA).Interior.Color = vbRed
        Else
            ' Test that all the items match
            ' This assumes that columns are in same order
            For columnNum = 2 To NUM_COLUMNS_DATA ' No need to test the ID column
                If sourceId.Cells(ColumnIndex:=columnNum).Value <> cellFound.Cells(ColumnIndex:=columnNum).Value Then
                    outputRange.Cells(ColumnIndex:=columnNum).Interior.Color = vbRed
                    copyTheData = True
                End If
            Next columnNum
        End If
        If copyTheData Then
            sourceId.Resize(ColumnSize:=NUM_COLUMNS_DATA).Copy
            ' Do PasteSpecial to avoid over-writing the ".Interior.Color = vbRed"
            outputRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Set outputRange = outputRange.Offset(RowOffset:=1)
            difference = difference + 1
        End If
        Set sourceId = sourceId.Offset(RowOffset:=1)
    Loop
```

Remember to test it thoroughly before using it on real data.

Comment: Thank you! :) i have tested the code and made some adjustments to suit my needs, When I export to sheet 3 how can I include the headers from sheet 1?

Comment: There are plenty of examples of that kind of thing. `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtSheet3).Range("A1").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtSheet1).Range("A1").Value`. Remember you can use the macro recorder to give you a starting point for a lot of things. Please mark my answer as accepted.